# An alternative definition of a group?

Tags: group-theory, logic

Will the following definition of a group work as a basis for group theory:

$\forall G,f,i,e (Group(G,f,i,e)\leftrightarrow f:G\times G\rightarrow G$

$\wedge i:G\rightarrow G$

$\wedge \forall x,y,z\in G (f(f(x,y),z)=f(x,f(y,z))$ (Associativity of $f$)

$\wedge e\in G$

$\wedge\forall x\in G(f(x,e)=x \wedge f(e,x)=x)$ (Identity under $f$)

$\wedge\forall x\in G(f(x,i(x))=e \wedge f(i(x),x)=e))$ (Inverse function $i$)

**Edit:** This is instead of the usual definition:

$\forall G,f (Group(G,f)\leftrightarrow f:G\times G\rightarrow G$

$\wedge \forall x,y,z\in G (f(f(x,y),z)=f(x,f(y,z))$

$\wedge\exists e\in G(\forall x\in G(f(x,e)=x\wedge f(e,x)=x)$

$\wedge\forall x\in G\exists x'\in G (f(x,x')=e \wedge f(x',x)=e)))$

Comment: A basis for group theory?

Comment: @AlexanderGruber As an alternative definition of a group.

Comment: How is this different from the usual definition?

Comment: It looks standard to me. What part of your definition is different from expected?

Comment: @wj32 There are no existential quantifiers, implicit or otherwise. An inverse function $i$ is explicitly defined, assuming the uniqueness of inverses, which the usual definition does not. But since inverses can be show to be unique using the usual definition, I thought this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: This looks like the general definition of a group. However, not all groups are [algebraic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_group). This is a different notion.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware of the distinction. Removed the word "algebraic."

Comment: @DanChristensen: That's what I meant. It's very easy to see that the two definitions are equivalent. So I don't understand the point of this question.

Comment: @wj32 I just wanted to know if they are indeed equivalent.

Comment: @DanChristensen: Yes, it is a good definition, and even (modestly) useful. It gives an equational definition, which has some structural advantages.

Comment: To me, the equational definition _is_ the standard one! But then again I am a categorist/logician...

Comment: If you look up universal algebra, you'll basically find this definition.  Also, you could call it an "involutive function" instead of an inverse function, since for all groups i(i(x))=x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the same definition.  The only differences are that your first one doesn't explicitly define the identity and inverse elements to be unique.  However, that can be easily proven  ($x*e^\prime=x\Leftrightarrow x^{-1}xe^\prime=x^{-1}x \Leftrightarrow ee^\prime= e \Leftrightarrow e^\prime= e$, and similarly for the inverses).

Answer (score 1):

The two definitions of group are equivalent. Furthermore, the notion of group homomorphism implied by the two definitions turn out to be equivalent as well.

It maybe interesting to contrast the definition of a ring as $(R,+,\times,0,1)$ satisfying equational identities, versus $(R,+,\times)$ satisfying axioms (including the existence of additive and multiplicative units).

While the two definitions define the same objects, they imply *different* notions of ring homomorphism: by the former definition, a homomorphism $f:R \to S$ should satisfy $f(1_R) = 1_S$. However, this need not be true for the latter definition.

A specific counterexample is $S = \mathbb{Z} / 6$, the integers modulo $6$, and $R = 3S$, the ring whose elements are the elements of $S$ divisible by $3$. The identity map $R \to S$ is a homomorphism according to the notion of homomorphism implied by the second definition of ring, but is *not* a homomorphism by the one implied by the first definition of ring.

Comment: Your observation is only true if one uses your way of deciding what a morphism should be given the definition...

Comment: That's what I meant by "implied", although in retrospect, the English word collides with the stricter mathematical word.